# jquery touchend event for entire document except the div that is clicked(tapped)

Tags: jquery, touch-event

I wanted to show/hide an element on click of a div in ipad/mobile devices. I have used touchstart and touchend events. But, I want to stop the touchend event for the div element '.view-list' so that the '.viewlist-popup' doesn't hide immediately.

```
<div class="view-list">VIEW LIST
          <div class="viewlist-popup">
          <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
</div>


$('.view-list').bind('touchstart', function() {
  $(this).find('.viewlist-popup').show();
 });

$(document).bind('touchend', function() {
  $('.view-list').find('.viewlist-popup').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter it by event target:

```
$(document).bind('touchend', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).hasClass('view-list')) return;
  $('.view-list').find('.viewlist-popup').hide();
});
```

And if you don't want to hide it on touching any of its decendants too:

```
if($(e.target).closest('.view-list').length) return;
```